# Can I use both @data and @builder annotations in one class Lombok?

Tags: java, lombok

The reason I want to use is because I want to generate setters in this format

For the class

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}


 public Person setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        return this;
    }

    public Person setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        return this;
    }
```

Instead of the @Data generated setters

```
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

Or is there any other way? Please let me know.

Comment: what is the difference? the setters u want to generate is similar to what @Data would generate isn't it?

Comment: Setters I want returns Person object but @Data gives me void as return type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For it, you should use `@Accessors(chain = true)`. For example:

```
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Setter
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

Vanilla java representation:

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Person setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        return this;
    }

    public Person setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's in experimental package right? Is it reliable? @xxxception

Comment: @user123, I have no reason to argue that it's not reliable (although this feature is experimental)